# numRenderBlockingRoundTrips parameter in googlepagespeed api

Tags: api, google-api, google-pagespeed, google-python-api

I am using googlepagespeedapi, now there are two parameters in pagestat that i do not understand .
These are
'numTotalRoundTrips': 10, 'numRenderBlockingRoundTrips': 0
Does roundtrips mean the redirections ? Please help.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then when you edit your question be sure to incldue a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe the issues you are having in detail.